# Gulp file producing root path rather than relative

Tags: javascript, gulp, less

I have the following Gulp file which runs Less, Autoprefixes, Concatinates files together then minifies everything - All less / dev fuctins are in a _dev folder and the compiled files are copied to a _web folder..

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var liveReload  = require('gulp-livereload');
var path = require('path');
var path = require('clean');
var moment = require('moment');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var jslint = require('gulp-jslint');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var concatJs = require('gulp-concat');




//LESS Task
gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src('./_dev/less/main.less')
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler (err) {
        notify.onError('LESS Error: <%= error.message %>')(err)
        this.emit('end')
      }
    }))
    .pipe(less())

   .pipe(rename("lessed.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_dev/css/'))

    .pipe(notify('Finished: <%= file.relative %>'))
})

//Autoprefixer
gulp.task('autoprefixed', function () {
  return gulp.src('./_dev/css/lessed.css')
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      cascade: false
    }))
 .pipe(rename("styles.css"))
    .pipe(notify('Autoprefixed (' + moment().format('MMM Do h:mm:ss A') + ')'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_dev/csscomp/'));
});


//Merge all CSS into one file
gulp.task('concatinate', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./node_modules/bootstrap3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', './_dev/csscomp/styles.css'])

   .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler (err) {
        notify.onError('Concat Error: <%= error.message %>')(err)
        this.emit('end')
      }
    }))
  .pipe(notify('Concat'))
    .pipe(concatCss("sitebundle.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_web/css/'))
     .pipe(notify('finished concatinating'));
});

gulp.task('concatstuff', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./node_modules/bootstrap3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', './_dev/csscomp/styles.css'])
    .pipe(concatCss("sitebundle.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_web/css/'))
});



//Minify
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('./_web/css/sitebundle.css')

        .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}, function(details) {
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize);
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize);
        }))
         .pipe(rename("styles.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_web/css/'))
        .pipe(notify('Minified..  ALL DONE'));
});

//Lint JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./_dev/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

//COMPRESS IMAGES
gulp.task('minimg' , function () {
  gulp.src('./_dev/images/*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/images'))
});

//GULP TASKS
//WATCH TASKS
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('./_dev/less/**/*.less', ['less']);   
  gulp.watch('./_dev/css/lessed.css', ['autoprefixed']); 
});

//DEFAULT
  gulp.task('default', function () {

  gulp.watch('./_dev/less/**/*.less', ['less']);   
  gulp.watch('./_dev/css/lessed.css', ['autoprefixed']); 
   gulp.watch('./_dev/csscomp/styles.css', ['concatinate']); 

  gulp.watch('./_web/css/sitebundle.css', ['minify-css']); 
  gulp.start('less');

});
```

I have an issue with paths - for example in my less file class i have the following background declaration -

```
 background:url('../images/link.png');
```

But after the file has been gulped the path of the file is -

```
background: url("../../../../_dev/csscomp/images/link.png") no-repeat
```

As you can see from teh gulp file - i have added a variety of file outputs along the route to see whats happeneing - the file remains with a relative filepath until it is copied over in the Concatinate task **(.pipe(gulp.dest('./*web/css/'))***

Its a complete scratcher and i cant understand how to fix it - can anyone offer any help and save my sanity!?

Comment: Try `.pipe(concatCss("sitebundle.css", {rebaseUrls:false}))`

Comment: spot on @Sven - i found that in teh docs - but hadnt added properties to a package before so didn't understand the required syntax - if yo add as answer i'll give you a tick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default [`gulp-concat-css`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css) tries to rebase the `url()` references in CSS files, see the project description:

> Concatenates css files, bubbling up @import statements (as per the standard), and **optionally rebasing urls** and inlining local @import statements.

This is useful if your concatenated file ends up in another location, but the referenced files stay were they are. The references then have to be adjusted.

In your case the `minimg` task copies the referenced images to the same location, so the relative paths in your CSS file can stay the same.

You can therefore disable url rebasing by providing the `rebaseUrls` option:

```
.pipe(concatCss("sitebundle.css", {rebaseUrls:false}))
```